# What does ./${SCRIPT##*/} mean in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking at a script that someone else wrote. There are several variables set including another script which is executed by way of variable interpolation as `./${SCRIPT##*/}`. I know that normally simply using `${SCRIPT}` accomplishes this. What is the `##*/` after `SCRIPT` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

> ${var##Pattern} Remove from $var the longest part of $Pattern that
>   matches the front end of $var.

In this particular example, it is greedily removing the pattern `*/`, which will remove all parts of the string stored in `SCRIPT` before and including the last `/`.

Consider the following example.

```
SCRIPT=/tmp/hiefe.txt
echo ./${SCRIPT##*/}
```

Output:

```
./hiefe.txt
```

Comment: I can see the usefulness of this. Especially in this case. The `SCRIPT` variable is set as a sub-directory of a user's `/home` directory (`~/bin/scripts`) but copied up to the user's `/home` directory on a remote server for execution rather than to a potentially non-existent `~/bin/scripts` directory.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

> ${var##Pattern} Remove from $var the longest part of $Pattern that matches the front end of $var.

So yeah, it basically returns the remainder of the path after the final `/`, contacted with `./`. Example:

```
>> SCRIPT=/test/set/of/path.text;echo ./${SCRIPT##*/}
./path.text
```